# Alternating row colours in javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I am developing a stock-ticker (slowly but surely as I am learning javascript)

It seems to be working well, and I am now trying to style the ticker.

The current code uses google finance to pull out the stock data, the html then returns this in div code. there is also a marquee scrolling affect and some css styling. I am familiar with the even and odd css rule which will make every alternating table row a different colour so it is easier on the eye but I believe i need to implement this in javascript as this is where the rows of data are created. The jquery does not use a table so I am a little unsure on how to do this, all my attempts have failed

I have attached the current project as a js fiddle and a example of what I am trying to achieve

Example: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLsy7zak/

```
var gstock = ["EPA:PIG","LON:AHT","NYSE:URI","NYSE:TEX" ,"NYSE:CAT", "NASDAQ:HEES",  "VIE:PAL" ];
$(document).ready(function () {
       for (var i = 0; i < gstock.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q="+gstock[i]+"&callback=?", function (response) {
            var stockInfo1 = response[0];
            var divContainer =  $('*[data-symbol="' + stockInfo1.t +'"]');

            var stockString1 = '<div class="stockWrapper">' + divContainer.data('title') + ':';
            var stockName1 = stockInfo1.t;             
            var stockChange ="";
            stockString1  += '<span class="stockSymbol "> '  +  stockInfo1.t + ' </span>';
            stockChange += '<span class="stockPrice "> '  +  stockInfo1.l  + '</span>';
            stockChange += '<span class="stockChange "> '  +  stockInfo1.c + '</span>';
            stockString1 += stockChange + '</div>';
            $("#title").append("<div>" + divContainer.data('title') + "</div>");
            $("#symbols").append("<div><b>" + stockInfo1.t + "</b></div>");

            $("#liveData").append("<div>" + stockChange + "</div>");
            divContainer.append(stockString1);

        });
    }
});
```

I suppose the question is:  how to get the scrolling ticker to alternate the row color so it appears nicer on the eye.

Thank you for your time

Comment: This is tabular data, is there any reason your *not* using a table?

Comment: because I was struggling to get the javascript in a table

Answer (score 6):

You *can* use CSS for this no problem:

```
marquee > div > div > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

However, because of the nature of your markup, you will have gaps between your 'cells'. You can remove the padding from the columns and apply it to the cells to lose the white gap:

```
marquee > div > div > div {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wLsy7zak/7/)

Comment: This is great, BUT the colour does not affect the padding. meaning that the rows of colour are broken up.

You can also test this in the JSfiddle.

Appreciating the help

Comment: That is because each individual 'cell' is coloured, not the row. With the current markup, that wouldn't be possible. You could remove the padding from your columns and apply it to the cells instead.

Comment: @George why this is not working   `$(".stockWrapper:even").css("background-color","blue"); 
             $(".stockWrapper:odd").css("background-color","yellow");`

Comment: @papsk Because the table isn't in rows, it's in columns.

Answer (score 0):

see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sibinva/wLsy7zak/8/)

Check whether this will help you to achieve by using script & css
put inside script

```
if(k%2){
           var cclass="redcolor";
       }else{
            var cclass="bluecolor";
       }
        k++;
```

like in the jsfiddle demo

and use the css to style the particular classes